# Can you change your character without losing items?

Tags: realm-of-the-mad-god

Can you change your character on Realm Of The Mad God without losing your items from your previous character?

Answer (score 4):

You have **vault** where you can put your items. Then, die with your previous character or buy the next slot for your new character.

Comment: Keep in mind that anything you put in your backpack will also be lost unless if you put it in your vault.  Backpacks are directly tied to a character.

Answer (score 0):

My guess is that you can put the items from your character in your vault( if your vault is empty) or let a good friend's character hold them, then die, then pick them back up with your new character.